# Apache: Configure "LogLevel debug" for certain modules only?

Tags: apache-2.2, unix, logging

I want to debug some authentication & authorization issues on my webserver, particularly with mod_authnz_ldap and other mod_auth* modules.

So I set `LogLevel debug` in the Apache configuration, either globally or for a single VirtualHost. This provides me with useful information from mod_authnz_ldap , but it also spews out a ton of noise from the SSL modules. See below for an example.

Is there a way to reduce the LogLevel for ssl_engine* , while still maintaining the loglevel for mod_authnz_ldap?

Yes, I could exclude the lines using something like `grep -v ssl_engine logfile`, but I also want to exclude this extra data from some other syslog parsing tools. I would rather reduce the logging from the source, instead of excluding it at the destination.

```
[Tue Jul 06 16:55:31 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): | 0100: 12 23 e7 0f 45 1f 1f d3-ed 12 f8 12 1f a9 90 85  .+..(........... |
[Tue Jul 06 16:55:31 2010] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(474): [client 10.10.10.123] [96991] auth_ldap authenticate: accepting joe
[Tue Jul 06 16:55:31 2010] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(730): [client 10.10.10.123] [96991] auth_ldap authorise: require group: authorisation successful (attribute memberUid) [Comparison true (cached)][Compare True]
[Tue Jul 06 17:02:17 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): | 0023: 23 ff 29 5a 4b bd 4c e6-bc 36 22 9c c3 22 c2 4b  ..)ZK.L..6u....K |
[Tue Jul 06 17:02:17 2010] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1830): | 0023: 23 ff 29 5a 4b bd 4c e6-bc 22 75 9c c3 b6 22 4b  ..)blahblah|
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, Jeopardy Style.

### Apache 2.3

This is possible in Apache 2.3.

[Apache > HTTP Server > Documentation > Version 2.4 > Per-module logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#permodule) says:

> **Per-module logging**
>
> The LogLevel directive allows you to specify a log severity level on a per-module basis. In this way, if you are troubleshooting a problem with just one particular module, you can turn up its logging
>   volume without also getting the details of other modules that you're
>   not interested in. This is particularly useful for modules such as
>   mod_proxy or mod_rewrite where you want to know details about what
>   it's trying to do.
>
> Do this by specifying the name of the module in your LogLevel directive:
>
> ```
> LogLevel info rewrite:trace5
> ```
>
> This sets the main LogLevel to info, but turns it up to trace5 for mod_rewrite.
>
> This replaces the per-module logging directives, such as RewriteLog, that were present in earlier versions of the server.

[Overview of new features in Apache HTTP Server 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html) say:

> Per-module and per-directory LogLevel configuration
>   The LogLevel can now be configured per module and per directory. New levels
>   trace1 to trace8 have been added above the debug log level.

Also see the discussion [on the Apache-dev](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/dev/385338) mailinglist.

### Apache 2.2 & Earlier:

No, this is not currently possible in Apache 2.2. The manual at HTTP Server > Documentation > Version 2.2 > Modules ["LogLevel Directive"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) does not show this option. The only option currently is to "grep -v" the offending lines.

### Apache 2.4 (proposed at time of writing):

This will be included with Apache 2.4. The Apache docs in [the trunk (2.3)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#loglevel) currently say:

> Compatibility:    Per-module and per-directory configuration is available
>   in Apache HTTP Server 2.3.6 and later

And:

> Specifying a level without a module
>   name will reset the level for all
>   modules to that level. Specifying a
>   level with a module name will set the
>   level for that module only. It is
>   possible to use the module source file
>   name, the module identifier, or the
>   module identifier with the trailing
>   _module omitted as module specification. This means the
>   following three specifications are
>   equivalent:
>
> ```
> LogLevel info ssl:warn
> LogLevel info mod_ssl.c:warn
> LogLevel info ssl_module:warn
> ```