# Making changes in Loglevel httpd.conf of apache server?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, logging, mod-rewrite

I am working on windows-7 Visual studio 2008,According to [Apache: Configure "LogLevel debug" for certain modules only?](https://serverfault.com/questions/158039/apache-configure-loglevel-debug-for-certain-modules-only/158369#158369) i am making changes in the loglevel of configuration file I am giving

```
LogLevel crit SampleLog_modules
```

After giving this statement in the configuration file i am unable to capture Critical or levels that are above critical only,my log file is capturing all the loglevels Starting from default loglevel warn,How can i capture only the events that are critical or above,Also tell significance of trace1,trace2 etc??

Comment: I am using ap_log_perror for log printing,when i am using ap_log_rerror it is working fine

Comment: Windoes 7 as a server isn't an environment we support. Please read our [about].